# Hosting Wcf Microservices in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, microservices

I'm building a Microservices archtectecture using Wcf and IIS, but I'm not completely sure if it all fulfills the definition of Microservices.

I have 4 Sites in IIS, each for a single service, which has exactly one responsibility. Wcf services are deployed to those sites and are used with the per call instance management. This would mean, that every request would spawn a net process, independent of each other for my understanding.

Soooo I'm not quite sure if this all fulfills the definition of Microservices and if there are other adequate approaches?
Every input is appreciated!

BR

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like micro-services, however the deployment aspect is only one part of it. Are these services light-weight, even though there is only one responsibility are they closed units that only provide responses to the caller or are some inter-dependencies?

It is not necessary for each service to be hosted separately to achieve a micro-services architecture, though it can help.

As long as the services are lightweight, loosely coupled and can be deployed and scaled independently, you could consider it to be Micro-Services.

When multiple services are deployed to the same IIS host, it could still be considered micro-services if each call that needs to call other services makes that call through a broker, queue, or via a load balancer, such that the call could be received and processed by an entirely different IIS instance when you scale out.

Some good references:

- [What is a Microservices Architecture?](https://www.tibco.com/reference-center/what-is-microservices-architecture)
- [Microservices - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices)

Answer (score 0):

Microservices had been a buzzword, especially in the last couple of years. As per [Martin Fowler](https://www.martinfowler.com/microservices/), the author of "Building Microservices: Designing Fine-Grained Systems",

> In short, the microservice architectural style is an approach to developing a
>   single application as a suite of small services, each running in its
>   own process and communicating with lightweight mechanisms, often an
>   HTTP resource API. These services are built around business
>   capabilities and independently deployable by fully automated
>   deployment machinery. There is a bare minimum of centralized
>   management of these services, which may be written in different
>   programming languages and use different data storage technologies.

The boundaries of Microservices are not well defined since it's a concept or a style. People tend to tweak it as per their need from time to time.

Looking at the description of you application, it does look like microservices. However, you need to answer a couple more questions if you want to call it a "true" microservice architecture.

- Can you scale Individual components of the Application? In your case each of the services?
- Do you have separate data sources for each of your services?
- Are they fault tolerant? Can one of your service run independently even if the other three are crashed?
- Are they stateless?

If you answer is "Yes" to all of the above, then you're on the right track. You can find more reference here

[Adopting Microservices at Netflix: Lessons for Architectural Design - Netflix](https://www.nginx.com/blog/microservices-at-netflix-architectural-best-practices/)

[Microservices by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html)